# What happens when I remove a portal shield?

Tags: ingress

You can protect a friendly portal by adding portal shields, but it is also possible to remove them afterwards. If I use this option to remove (my own) portal shield, what happens to it? Will it return to my inventory, or will it be lost?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The shield will be lost when it is removed. You don't get it again.

**EDIT: 27/04/15**

***Added new shield: Axa Shield, and new shielding values***

Now the shields have other protection:

- Basic : +30
- Rare: +40
- Very Rare: +60
- Axa Shield: +70

**NOW Shields can't be removed**

<strike>TAKE care with it, if you have the new shields, remove your old shields in your portals, and replace it with the new ones.</strike>

This shields.. are...very... helpful for your faction (or not if the portal is of the other faction)

**EDIT 2**

If you have "old" shields in your possession (this one that have C:+6 R:+8 VR:+10 )
DON'T USE IT! First of all, DROP it, then acquire it again. Why would you do this? That is because, when it is dropped the game recalculate the values of the shields, so the old one convert to the new one.

I mean, if you have a common shield (+10) and you drop it, and acquire it again, the shield will take the new values (+30)

Comment: Shields are no more removable so this question and also its answer have both lost their meaning. This QA should be left here just for historical reasons and no more be edited.